# React component that reads from a .txt file and displays data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a react component that reads from a .txt file with in my project and displays the text. Not sure where to start.  I know how to call the component but not code for the component.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a Node.js default module called `fs`

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('myfile.txt', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  // Do your stuff here
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get values to pass into your React component then you can try turning it into a JSON file
and then

```
 import data from '<path_to_json_file>';
```